# My function only works with an alert after my ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm populating a table with values from my database. I have included a delete icon in rows which can be deleted. The image has an `onclick='deleteCat(id);'` property, the id is taken from a json array trough a loop like so:

`string = "<td align='center'><a href=''><img border='0' src='../images/Bullet-Delete.png' alt='delete' onclick='deleteCat("+json[i]['id']+");'/></a></td>";`

This is my `deleteCat` function:

```
function deleteCat(id){
    var dataString = "catId=" + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
        url: "../ajax/categorie_verwijderen.php",
        data: dataString,  
        success: function(data) {
                //$("#allecat").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                //update_table();                
        }
   });   
   //alert(id);
}
```

My function works when I put an alert after the ajax. The table refreshes and the row is removed from my db. However when I remove the alert my function does not work, the table is refreshed and the row is still present in the table and db.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can also put this line @ the top of your javascript , window.alert=null;

Comment: Will use it if I can't solve the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent the default event for the click - ie the page is being reloaded each time you click on the image

```
function deleteCat(id){
    var dataString = "catId=" + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
        url: "../ajax/categorie_verwijderen.php",
        data: dataString,  
        success: function(data) {
                $("#allecat").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                update_table();                
        }
   });   
   return false; // prevent the browser following the href
}
```

You will also need to change your html :

```
onclick='return deleteCat("+json[i]['id']+");
```

Comment: @GlennVanCauwenbergh updated my answer - see the bottom bit about adding `return` to the `onclick` call

Answer (score 1):

The alert() helps because that delays the processing of the remaining javascript in that function. The ajax send data  asynchronously. async key is Default: true and should change it to **false** in your call till the client wait for end of ajax call.
e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
  async:false,
  url: "test.html",
  .
  .

});
```

Comment: This worked for me because I was using a `button` inside a `dialog`. Since it was a button(and not a link), the default action was not to navigate to a URL.  This is why `preventDefault()` wouldn't work here.  

I really just needed have the function wait until the request was completed, so setting `async:false` did it for me.